# How to check if wifi location service is on...?

Tags: android, location

I am working on an application that uses the location of the user.

I can successfully ask the user for wifi and gps enable.
As you know you can have WiFi on but prevent it from providing your location.

The thing is i want to ask the user to enable the wifi location obtain service if it is disabled. I use a wifi manager for wifi and a LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED for GPS.And both work great.

```
//provider variable code
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);



//i use the string into an if statement
if (!provider.contains("gps")){ 

}
```

And i understand that i can get enabled providers into a variable separated with comma.
It works great..but "gps" is the name for GPS but what is the name for WiFi into the string???

Comment: Best to mark the Answer as the correct Answer...simple step to repay someone for going out of their own way to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two providers.  One is GPS, the other is called network, and includes Wifi and cell towers.

So if both providers are enabled, the response you get is `network,gps`

Comment: I solved it myself just didn't have the time to answer :P Thanks a lot this is the solution :)

Comment: I marked it didn't know how to do it but i found out :) many thanks :)